# Was Charles Russel, Founder of the Jehovah's Witnesses, a Freemason?

Tags: jehovahs-witnesses, freemasonry

I've heard it stated that the founder of Jehovah's Witnesses, Charles Taze Russel, was a Freemason (33rd Degree) which may have been partially responsible for his interest in collaborating bible prophecy with the pyramids, as well as the symbolism he used in some of his books.

There seems to be arguments both for and against this, both convincing. Is there any solid historical proof of as to whether or not this claim is true?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Charles Taze Russel (or Russell) is [reported](http://www.pastor-russell.com/life/mason1.html) to have said, in a Convention discourse "The Temple of God"

> Although I have never been a Mason, I have heard that in Masonry they have something which very closely illustrates this ...  Many Masons shake hands with me and give me what I know is their grip; they don't know me from a Mason.  Something I do seems to be the same as Masons do, I don't know what it is; but they often give me all kinds of grips and I give them back, then I tell them I don't know anything about it except just a few grips that have come to me naturally.

Russel appears not to have been an entirely honest man, but nevertheless is unlikely to have been hiding a secret allegiance to the Freemasons, as he talks of such societies consuming valuable time in foolish, senseless rites and ceremonies.

Comment: This document seems to put the issue to rest https://watchtowerdocuments.org/charles-taze-russell-was-not-a-pennsylvania-freemason/

Answer (score 3):

**Was Charles Russel, Founder of the Jehovah's Witnesses, a Freemason?**

The short answer is that we may never know one way or another with any certainty. There seems to be arguments both for and against this topic. The debate will no doubt go on.

Charles Taze Russel freely admits he had friends that were Freemasons. He even shacked hands with them with their **”grips”**. At face value it ends there.

> "There are certain conditions,—the low gate, the narrow way, the difficult path.  Although I have never been a Mason, I have heard that in Masonry they have something which very closely illustrates this" ...  "Many Masons shake hands with me and give me what I know is their grip; they don't know me from a Mason.  Something I do seems to be the same as Masons do, I don't know what it is; but they often give me all kinds of grips and I give them back, then I tell them I don't know anything about it except just a few grips that have come to me naturally." —June, 1913; Convention discourse "The Temple of God"("Convention Report Sermons" pg. 362)
>
> [Was Pastor Russell a Freemason?](https://www.pastor-russell.com/life/mason1.html)

Wikipedia goes on to further state that Pastor Russell was not a Freemason!

> In June 1913, during a transcontinental speaking tour, Russell lectured in a Masonic hall in San Francisco, saying:
>
> > Although I have never been a Mason… Something I do seems to be the same as Masons do, I don't know what it is; but they often give me all kinds of grips and I give them back, then I tell them I don't know anything about it except just a few grips that have come to me naturally.
>
> [Charles Taze Russell](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_Taze_Russell)

My only concern here is in the fact that Charles Russell sometimes employed Masonic grips with Freemasons. These grips would have been secret hand gestures known to Freemasons alone.

> **Symbols in ritual**
>
> Historically, Freemasons used various signs (hand gestures), grips or "tokens" (handshakes), and passwords to identify legitimate Masonic visitors from non-Masons who might wish to gain admission to meetings. These signs, grips, and passwords have been exposed multiple times; today Freemasons use dues cards and other forms of written identification.
>
> [Masonic ritual and symbolism](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Masonic_ritual_and_symbolism)

My only real question here is why did Pastor Russell employ Masonic hand gestures with Masons if he was not a Freemason? It does not abode well with his statement that he was not a Freemason.

Comment: https://watchtowerdocuments.org/charles-taze-russell-was-not-a-pennsylvania-freemason/